# return url doesn't get properly decoded after login

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, login, url-encoding

When accessing SO with a bookmark that has a list of tags separated by `or`, for instance:

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html%20or%20javascript?tab=newest&pagesize=50`

When logging in from this URL, the browser ends up redirected to `http://stackoverflow.com/users/login?returnurl=%2fquestions%2ftagged%2fhtml+or+javascript#log-in`

[image: Before logging in]

After logging in, the URL the browser gets redirected to is `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htmlorjavascript`, which obviously isn't a very popular tag.

[image: after logging in]
This is Firefox 13.0.1, by the way.

---

**UPDATE**

Further testing reveals that <kbd>whitespace</kbd> or `%20` get encoded to `+` when pressing the `login` button, and that `+` gets ignored when decoding the url to redirect to after the login.

*But*, if the initial URL contains <kbd>+</kbd> instead of <kbd>whitespace</kbd> or `%20`, the url when logging in contains the tags separated by `%2b`. They get decoded correctly to `+` when redirecting after the login so it works properly if the tags in the URL are separated by <kbd>+</kbd>.

Such a pity Firefox decodes <kbd>+</kbd> and `%2B` to <kbd>whitespace</kbd> when used in a bookmark.

Comment: Just you wait! Some day, the [tag:htmlorjavascript] tag will be the most popular on SO, and you'll be sorry you **mocked it**!

Comment: Just encountered same issue - after login the URL I was returned to had `%20` and `*` characters removed. However, this is with Chromium, not Firefox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was an issue of overly aggressive URL sanitization. Fixed in the next build.

Comment: Not fixed according to [this new report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182022/152859) and I just reproduced it myself.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd It seems fixed at least for URL's not including `+` signs. Works fine for `html%20or%20javascript` and `html+or+javascript` as of now. Didn't try using `+` and other characters though.

Comment: @XaviLópez I see. Still, the fix is not complete as there are plenty of tags containing the + character.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd looks like this was an issue of the ' ' character not being encoded and decoded the same way, and in order for tags to be parsed correctly, spaces need to be preserved and not converted to a `+`.   Should be fixed in the next build.