# Broken tagsearch after logging in via google

Tags: bug

My bookmark to start on SO is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20-qt which lists c++ questions without qt questions just fine. However sometimes I am starting logged out, and then on that page I click on login which sends me to https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?returnurl=%2fquestions%2ftagged%2fc%252b%252b%2b-qt which then after logging in via google sends me to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b+-qt afterwards.

Note how the %20 in the initial url somehow got transformed to a + which will then be interpreted by SO for searching questions tagged "c+++-qt". I tried this on FF21 and Chrome28, and since both are showing the same behaviour I am suspecting a bug on SO.

It might also be a problem with the way SO interacts with google login, in which case SO might want to implement a workaround here.

Comment: Double encoding issue, that's all. Got nothing to do with Google, it will happen with any type of login you choose.